# Attaching a file with email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, email-attachments

I am trying to upload a file to my server, save the file along with some form data, and send the file along with the email to the user. It is doing everything right expect for the sending the attachment. It sends the email just fine without the attachment but when I try to attach one, the email comes in with the title, but no body. On the email it does show the paper clip icon like it recognizes it has an attachment but there is no body or no way to see the attachment.

```
if(!empty($email)) {
$this->load->library('email');
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';   
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'website.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('no-reply@website.com', 'Website');

$this->email->subject($subject);
$message = $this->email_format($message);
$this->email->message($message);            
if(!empty($file)) { 
    $this->email->attach($file);
}
```

}

I tried sending it through default server and still the same results. Was thinking that since its sending through gmail it might block attachments but no luck. I have tried using all different types of path. Before I send the email I upload the file to the server using codeingiters upload class and tried using its response file_path and full_path vars but still the same results. Any ideas what it could possibly be?

Thanks

Comment: what is `$file` path ??

Comment: What you get for this `$this->email->send(); echo $this->email->print_debugger();`

Comment: print_debugger cames back with "<pre>↵↵</pre>" its an ajax request.

Comment: This is the path -> /home/network/public_html/network/uploads/2016/04/bw_182.png Also tried /uploads/2016/04/bw_183.png. Cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you use smtp for sending the e-mail, you should set the $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
Your code seems to be right btw. Can you show us the whole code for this function? Without additional informations I cant see any problem.